# c3.js Donut Chart: Making the separator line visible on a 100% arc?

Tags: svg, c3.js, donut-chart

I'm trying to style a donut chart in c3.js and when an arc is 100% of the donut, it looks like for every arc but the last category, a thin white line is shown at the top of the donut. On the last category this line is missing, and we're trying to get it to show up so the charts look consistent. I've already played around a little bit with the stroke style for the `.c3-chart-arc` class but haven't been having any luck. Is there a way to make this thin line separator show up on the last category of a donut chart?

Answer (score 0):

With just one value the donut is actually a donut - two circles - with the area in between filled in, so there's no way to affect the donut's drawing properties to get the effect you want.

The hacky answer though (using c3's internal property) is that after setting up such a chart, you can draw a line from near the centre of the chart straight up like so to mimic the effect:

```
d3.select(".c3-chart-arcs").append("line")
    .attr ({x1: 0, y1: -20, x1: 0, y1: -chart.internal.currentHeight / 2})
    .style ("stroke", "white")
;
```